# Bitcoin exchange language coding

Tags: php

I am looking at coding a Bitcoin trading exchange,  Would PHP be sufficient for an order matching engine?  The server would be load balanced with running MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have built exchanges with PHP and MySQL. I would also recommend Redis for caching.

Comment: Cheers! appreciate it, will look into Redis.

Comment: does it support row locking like innodb?